# VBA ListBox with Offset Columns

Tags: vba, listbox, offset, userform

I'm using the following code to populate a ListBox. Column 1 of the ListBox comes from Column F of my worksheet, and the second column of the ListBox comes from the next column over. But I'm wanting to have that second ListBox column come from column D of the worksheet (2 to the left). And I just can't make the offset work the way I want.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim dic As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ky As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set rng = Sheet4.Range("F2")

    Do
        If Not dic.exists(rng.Value) Then
            dic.Add rng.Value, rng.Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            dic(rng.Value) = dic(rng.Value) + rng.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Loop Until rng.Value = ""

    For Each ky In dic.keys
        With BWListBox3
            .AddItem
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ky
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Application.Text(dic(ky), "[h]:mm") 
        End With
    Next ky

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 to the left?

```
    If Not dic.exists(rng.Value) Then
        dic.Add rng.Value, rng.Offset(, -2).Value
    Else
        dic(rng.Value) = dic(rng.Value) + rng.Offset(, -2).Value
    End If
```

Comment: I just tried it myself and it worked fine for me...?

Comment: Ok...I set up a sample workbook, and you're right the code works.  So any idea what could be causing the mismatch in my actual workbook?

Comment: When you get the error, click debug, and use the immediate window to check the values. Are they both numeric?

Comment: Nevermind...I missed the -2 on the first line.  It works now.  Thanks so much!!